# Ajax CORS always fails although I do get a valid response from server

Tags: cors, cross-domain, fetch

I have a AWS Lambda function attached to API gateway. I have been trying to set up CORS all day, but I can't figure out what is going on here.

This is the client request:

```
        var endPoint = 'https://776v8jadw0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sandbox/helpwithprogramming/contact';
        var payload = {message: 'Hello there'};
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',  '*');
        var options = {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: headers,
          mode: 'cors',
          cache: 'default',
          body: JSON.stringify(payload)
        };

        fetch(endPoint, options)
          .then(res => {
            console.log('ok', res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
           console.log('error', err);
       });
```

My response headers for the OPTIONS method are as follows from API gateway:

```
access-control-allow-headers:Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,Authorization,X-Amz-Date,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token
access-control-allow-methods:DELETE,GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PATCH,POST,PUT
access-control-allow-origin:*
content-length:0
content-type:application/json
date:Mon, 11 Dec 2017 05:33:59 GMT
status:200
```

And I get the following response from API gateway when the POST is executed:

```
{message: "Hello from Lambda"}
```

However, my fetch call actually fails, and goes into the catch block with the following error:

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

And Chrome displays this message in the console:

> Failed to load
>   https://776v8jadw0.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/sandbox/helpwithprogramming/contact:
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Try force-reloading to ensure you're not getting a cached response that your browser cached before you added the headers. Or try from a different browser. And remove the `headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');` part from your frontend code.You don't want to send that header in the request: it's strictly a response header for servers to send back.

Comment: I was able to solve it. I needed to add ('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*') to both the OPTIONS, and the POST responses from api gateway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AWS Console Navigate to API Gateway.

1. Select the **API** which is been deployed.
2. Select the HTTP method for ex: *GET,POST* in **RESOUCES** and click on Actions.
3. Select **Enable CORS** in RESOURCE ACTIONS and add **'*'** to 
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin and enable CORS.